# PyGame only blits last of loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm working on an app that draws a square on peoples faces (very basic but not the easiest).
It only prints 1 square instead of 2+.

For example, this is the output:

[image]

output wished for (Photoshop obv):

[image]

code (snipped):

```
 while x <= faces:
    print(x)
    image_height = int(response[x]["faceRectangle"]["height"]) * image_modifier_height
    image_top = int(response[x]["faceRectangle"]["top"]) * image_modifier_height  # - image_height/2
    image_left = int(response[x]["faceRectangle"]["left"]) * image_modifier_width
    image_width = int(response[x]["faceRectangle"]["width"]) * image_modifier_width

    upper_line = (image_left, image_top)
    bottom_line = (image_left, image_top + image_height)
    right_line = (image_left + image_width, image_top)

    # print("top: {}".format(image_top))
    # print("left: {}".format(image_left))
    # print("width: {}".format(image_width))
    # print("height: {}".format(image_height))
    # print("upper_line: {}".format(upper_line))
    # print("bottom_line: {}".format(bottom_line))
    # print("right_line: {}".format(right_line))

    horizontal_line = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Wit\PycharmProjects\LauEnv\Python learning\img\horizontalline.png')
    horizontal_line = pygame.transform.scale(horizontal_line, (int(image_width), 5))
    vertical_line = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Wit\PycharmProjects\LauEnv\Python learning\img\verticalline.png')
    vertical_line = pygame.transform.scale(vertical_line, (5, int(image_height)))

    image_ = pygame.transform.scale(image_, (512, 512))
    size = (512, 512)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

    emotion = max(response[x]["faceAttributes"]["emotion"].items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
    emotion = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', int(image_height / 10)).render(emotion, True, [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255])

    age = str(int(response[x]["faceAttributes"]["age"]))
    age = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', int(image_height / 10)).render(age, True, [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255])

    gender = response[x]["faceAttributes"]["gender"]
    gender = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', int(image_height / 10)).render(gender, True, [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255])

    screen.blit(image_, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(horizontal_line, upper_line)
    screen.blit(horizontal_line, bottom_line)
    screen.blit(vertical_line, upper_line)
    screen.blit(vertical_line, right_line)
    screen.blit(emotion, (upper_line[0], upper_line[1] - int(image_height / 8)))
    screen.blit(age, (upper_line[0], upper_line[1] - int(image_height / 8) * 2))
    screen.blit(gender, (upper_line[0], upper_line[1] - int(image_height / 8) * 3))
```

Face list/dic:

```
[{'faceRectangle': {'top': 157, 'left': 48, 'width': 349, 'height': 349}, 'faceAttributes': {'gender': 'female', 'age': 18.0,
                                                                                                    'emotion': {'anger': 0.0, 'contempt': 0.0, 'disgust': 0.0, 'fear': 0.0,
                                                                                                                'happiness': 0.0, 'neutral': 0.999, 'sadness': 0.0,
                                                                                                                'surprise': 0.0}}},
        {'faceRectangle': {'top': 144, 'left': 594, 'width': 341, 'height': 341}, 'faceAttributes': {'gender': 'male', 'age': 62.0,
                                                                                                     'emotion': {'anger': 0.023, 'contempt': 0.054, 'disgust': 0.0, 'fear': 0.0,
                                                                                                                 'happiness': 0.0, 'neutral': 0.922, 'sadness': 0.001,
                                                                                                                 'surprise': 0.0}}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I put "screen.blit(image_, (0, 0))" in the loop which overwrites every square.